# In 1940 ”where” the industrial use showed a significant increase in value

Tags: word-usage

I am writing an essay in which I am reporting the data provided on this line graph[image]
And I came to the point where I need to describe the changes in the industrial use.

So I wrote:

> In 1900, the domestic use stood at 100 km3 and this value was steady over the next 40 years until 1940 **where** the industrial use showed a significant rise to hit the 1,000 km3 point in 2000.

Is the usage of the conductive pronoun **where** correct in the context?

Comment: A Google search returns just **3** instances of the collocation ["conductive pronoun"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22conductive+pronoun%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&oq=%22conductive+pronoun%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2423j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Luckily, one of them is some blogger claiming it's an alternative name for a ***relative pronoun*** (for him, perhaps, but obviously not for many others! :)

Comment: Because the cited text is in the context of a ***graph*** (which represents "time" on a ***spatial*** axis), it's quite natural to use "locational" ***where*** rather than "chronological" ***when***. But this apparent "looseness" sometimes occurs in other contexts ***where / when*** there's no obvious reason to justify the choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the contradiction here is between referring to both real time and its graphical interpretation (time vs space): year numbers are not defined as graph points, and the verbs are in past tense (like in a usual event description). If you use terms like '**1940 point**' and '**1,000 km3 value**' plus change verbs' tense to Present, then 'where' (*1940 point, where the value starts to rise*, etc.) and the rest things will be OK to describe the graph.